# Ruby on Rails sum, difference and product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in Ruby on Rails, how would I write code to solve this problem ? "Write a program that takes two numbers from a user and shows the sum, difference, product and quotient of the 2 numbers"

Answer (score 1):

create file calc.rb

```
   class Calc
    def sum(a,b)
       a + b
    end

    def mul(a,b)
        a * b
    end

    def diff(a,b)
        a - b
    end

    def div(a,b)
        a / b
    end
end

puts "Enter A"
a = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Enter B"
b = gets.chomp.to_i
obj = Calc.new
p "sum: #{obj.sum(a,b)}"
p "product: #{obj.mul(a,b)}"
p "quotient: #{obj.div(a,b)}"
p "difference: #{obj.diff(a,b)}"
```

run this one in console

> ruby calc.rb

```
Enter A
4
Enter B
2
"sum: 6"
"product: 8"
"quotient: 2"
"difference: 2"
```

Comment: Thanks Nataraja. After studying the problem for some time, I did manage to write a slightly different solution. I do appreciate your help. I'm a complete newb in a coding bootcamp ! ! !